# AD on premises integration to windows azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a little confusion about directory sync which is used for AD azure integration.

1) Can anyone let me know, whether we can integrate complete on premises AD to 
   windows azure AD using this? Or only users and groups?

2) If directory sync will not be helpful for complete AD integration what 
   method will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone let me know, whether we can integrate complete on-premises AD to windows azure AD using this ? or only users and groups?

Yes, your on-premises AD can be integrated with Azure AD (AAD) with AAD Connect tool. The integration needs prerequisites you can refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-prerequisites. It means not all the cases can be done. For example, if you need to use password writeback functionality, your on-premises AD domain controller must be at least Windows Server 2008. Another prerequisite is that if your on-premises is using single label domain, it is not supported. Best to check the link above before the integration.

> IF directory sync will not be helpful for complete AD integartion what methord will be used ?

AAD Connect provides set of features to help you build a comprehensive hybrid identity between on-premises AD and AAD. However, if this doesn't meet your requirement, you can build some extensions programmatically to interact with AAD. I don't know your preferred programming language, but here is the Authentication Library (ADAL) which is pretty much preferred for AAD development https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries

AAD not only supports user and group sync, but also for custom attributes, filtering, password sync & writeback or so on. Remember AAD Connect is purposely for synchronization. It does not offer too much for AAD interaction (saying that you need to manage, add more attributes or retrieve user attributes, 3rd integration...)

Comment: Since OP is talking about directory sync, it might be good to also remind that the "DirSync" tool is not supported anymore. AAD Connect is the replacement, which you did mention :)